# XMLSerializer - Class added to Namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, namespaces, webbrowser-control

I have been stuck on this problem for the last 2 days and still haven't made it work and I am looking for some help.

My `Listbox` gets generated items added to it depending on the item selected in the `Combobox`. When I click the button `Create` a new Window appears with a `WebBrowser` object inside of it.

**(Wasnt allowed to upload image so it is contained in the link)**

This is the screen with the list box with the items generated and also the button that is clicked.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozI7O.jpg

**Button Click Event**

This gets the item selected in the Combobox. Then it creates a new instance of the Alrighty Class with the property called Standards with the List of items (The items from the Listbox). The property gets populated with the third line and then I have another class named SaveXML (See Below) and this saves in XML. Then will open the browser.

```
string selectedStandard = (string)cmbStandard.SelectedItem;
Alrighty info = new Alrighty();
info.Standards = _standardDefinitions;
SaveXML.SaveData(info, string.Format("{0}.xml", selectedStandard));

HTMLBrowser boss = new HTMLBrowser(selectedStandard);
boss.Show();
```

**SaveXML Class**

```
public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
{
    XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
    sr.Serialize(writer, obj);
    writer.Close();
}
```

**The Problem**

When I click the button and get onto the Window with the `Web Browser` on this code appears:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am1fU.jpg

As you can see from the blue box, When I delete this code and add the code in for my `Stylesheet` everything works fine, but the problem is the code in the blue box keeps getting generated, is there a way to not get this code in the `XML` file that is created.

**Extra**

How can I get this string to appear instead of the generated code in the blue box:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="StandardXS.xsl"?>
```

EDIT:

```
public class SaveXML
{
    public static void SaveData(object obj, string filename)
    {

        //empty namespace and empty value
        XmlSerializerNamespaces alright = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        alright.Add("", "");

        XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);

        sr.Serialize(writer, obj, alright);
        writer.Close();

    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) { writer.WriteAttributeString(@"<?xml-stylesheet type=text/xsl href=StandardXS.xsl?>", string.Empty); }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespace = new     XmlSerializerNamespaces();

//empty namespace and empty value
namespace.Add("", "");

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(someType);

//Serialize the object with custom namespace
serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, myObj, namespace);
```

For adding a custom attribute, as I said in the comments, implement IXmlSerializable and implement WriteXml and add your custom attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it deleted all the things in the blue box but didn't delete the actual <Alrighty> Tags.

Comment: Alrighty is the name of your class. If you want to serialize without that tag you will need to implement IXmlSerializable and implement WriteXml and if you want to read ReadXml

Comment: Is it possible to get the tag `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="StandardXS.xsl"?>` to appear?

Comment: public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteAttributeString(@"<?xml-stylesheet type=text/xsl href=StandardXS.xsl?>", string.Empty);
        }

Comment: I added that code to the SaveXML class but where would i call that method.

Comment: The framework will call it for you when you use XmlSerializer

Comment: Is my edit on my question correct because it still doesnt work.